# Need help importing Asset Reporting Format (ARF) XML report into PowerShell xml variable

Tags: xml, powershell, undefined, prefix

I need some help figuring out if there is a quick fix to importing an ARF xml report into a PowerShell [xml]$var; when getting the following error.

```
Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error "'cmd-sc' is an undeclared prefix.
```

This error seems to only be present when Unix/Linux information is included in the arf (xml) report.  The arf report itself is about 250 MB; and that is just for a test setup with 4 systems; AND there were over 1,000 hits for "cmd-sc" when I performed a search.  So this is not something I think I can manually modify.

The specific line creating the error is:

```
<cmd-sc:shellcommand_item id="1">
```

However this may not be a single liner, for example, this instance of this element looks like this"

```
<cmd-sc:shellcommand_item id="1">
    <cmd-sc:command>passing=&quot;&quot;;output=&quot;&quot;;EPG=....[some really long logic]</cmd-sc:command>
    <cmd-sc:line_selection>.+</cmd-sc:line_selection>
    <cmd-sc:exit_status datatype="int">0</cmd-sc:exit_status>
    <cmd-sc:stdout_line>All groups in /etc/passwd exist in /etc/group</cmd-sc:stdout_line>
    <cmd-sc:stdout_line>XCCDF_RESULT:PASS</cmd-sc:stdout_line>
    <cmd-sc:stderr_line> status="does not exist"/>
</cmd-sc:shellcommand_item>
```

I'm relatively new working with XML, so I though maybe the hyphen was creating the problem, so I replaced "cmd-sc" with "cmdssc", but came up with the same error.  I then tried replacing "<cmd-sc:" with "<cmd cmd-sc:" and "</cmd-sc:" with "</cmd cmd-sc:" thinking maybe the colon was the issue and by adding a leading cmd, that maybe it would correct it'self, but this too seems to have failed.

The command I am using to try to load the xml file into an xml variable is:

```
[xml]$report = Get-Content .\arf_report.xml
```

and I've tried using the full file path...it's nothing to do with the file path; as I know there is usually someone who will comment on that ;p

Comment: You need a namespace attribute in the xml like xmlns:cmd-sc="http://myurl"

Comment: Thanks jdweng, that's just what I needed.